# How to implement custom nebula GridHeaderRenderer implementation?

Tags: java, grid, swt, jface, nebula

There doesn't seem to be enough documentation here to work with, when I create a GridHeaderRenderer  there are three methods to implement, but the measure and notify methods are a mystery to me, and the on the paint one I don't know how much room I have to work with.

I know the users can change size of the headers, so how do I find out the actual size at the minute, what do I provide from "measure" and what about notify?

A big help would be if anyone has an example implementation? I have to draw and image and write the header text in.